# How to give an upper bound of the maximum eigenvalue of $A B A^T$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let $A \in {\mathbb R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in {\mathbb R}^{n \times n}$, where $A$ has full row rank and $B > 0$ (positive definite).

Then, how to give an upper bound of the maximum eigenvalue $\rho(A B A^T)$ in terms of the singular values of $A$ and the maximum eigenvalue of $B$?

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of what? You should have a bound of the form $\sigma^2\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the biggest eigenvalue of $B$ and $\sigma$ the biggest singular value of $A$ (biggest = biggest absolute value)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks very much for your answer! Could you give me a hint about the proof?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I Thanks for your answer (that deleted one), and I think I find a simple answer $\sigma^2 \lambda = \|A\|_2 \|B\|_2 \|A^T\|_2 \geq \|A B A^T\|_2 \geq \rho(A B A^T)$.

Comment: That sounds about right! Only be careful, since you are working with real matrices and not complex ones, it might be that $\|B\|_2>\lambda$ (but I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks a lot! In this question, $B$ is positive definite, which means the maximum sigular value (i.e., $\|B\|_2$) equals the maximum eigenvalue. Thus, I think $\lambda = \|B\|_2$ would be correct. Thanks!

Comment: It is certainly true if $B$ is also symmetric (so that it is diagonalizable).

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks very much for DanielRobert-Nicoud's help. I have solved this problem, but the answer was hidden in the conversations between DanielRobert-Nicoud and I. Now, I post an answer here as a summary of our conversations so that one can find the answer directly.

Let $\sigma$ be the maximum singular value of $A$, and we get $\sigma = \|A\|_2 = \|A^{\mathrm T}\|_2$. Since $B$ is symmetric, we have $\rho(B) = \|B\|_2$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ returns the spectral radius for a given matrix. Now, we get the following result

$$\sigma^2 \rho(B) = \|A\|_2 \|B\|_2 \|A^{\mathrm T}\|_2 \geq \|ABA^{\mathrm T}\|_2 = \rho(ABA^{\mathrm T}).$$

Therefore, an upper bound for $\rho(ABA^{\mathrm T})$ is $\sigma^2 \rho(B)$.